# Менять класс у родительского или у всех дочерних элементов?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Уже в голове перебрал кучу реализаций, но ни как не могу придти к нужной!

**Проект делаю на Vue**

Есть список товаров, хочу реализовать изменение вида карточек товара (list и table). **Карточка товара КОМПОНЕНТ**, как лучше сделать, добавить для компонента v-bind:class и в зависимости от выбранного типа отображения товара менять class (но тогда мне кажется сильно затратно, например поменять у 100 товаров class, но зато в компоненте можно сразу описать стиль для --list и --table вида) или проще менять у родительского блока в котором выводится компонент, но тогда придется перебивать стиль компонента например:

```
.listGoods{
  &--table{
    .product{
      // новый стиль 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: На подобные вопросы не может быть однозначного ответа, т.к. логика решения целиком зависит от задачи и сценариев использования. В вопросе эта информация отсутствует.

Comment: Естественно, чем меньше действий выполняется кодом (и браузером) для успешного достижения цели, тем лучше.

Comment: @yar85 да сложно всё описать ) Пришел к тому что в компоненте добавлю такую конструкцию .view-list { .productItem{ // стиль в виде списка } }, то есть если в каком то месте буду выводить данный компонент и там понадобится стиль в виде списка, то родителю просто добавляем класс и всё. Я думаю это более оптимальный вариант решения данной задачи.

Comment: Если все дочерние компоненты (или большинство их) зависят от родителя, то конечно, это оптимально. А когда много дочерних могут перекрывать родительские стили, то оптимальнее будет прямо на них переключать классы (это относительно дешевая операция - по крайней мере, дешевле рендеринга заново, как с v-if). Но факторов много, на самом деле: чем больше дополнительной логики связано с выводом, тем сложнее найти баланс, предусмотреть все...